# Is $ P(B) = P(A \cap B)$ if $P(A)=1$?

Tags: probability

Let $A,B$ denote events and suppose $P(A)=1$. Then is
$$
P(B) = P(A \cap B)?
$$
Certainly $P(B) \geq P(A \cap B)$ but I have troubles finding counterexamples to support a strict inequality, or prove the opposite inequality.

Comment: Intuitively, if P(A)=1, then A is the universe, which means that B is a subset of A, which means that B=A∩B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A hint for how to prove it: decompose $\mathbb P(B)$ as $\mathbb P(B \cap A) + \mathbb P(B \cap A^c)$ and see what you can do to the rightmost term.